# How to rewrite URL in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am facing some issue with url rewrite for wordpress

I have URL like this:

```
http://example.com/mentor-profile/?mentor_slug=dr-jonathan-fass
http://example.com/mentor-profile/?mentor_slug=neha
```

This is not user and SEO friendly, I want URL like this:

```
http://example.com/dr-jonathan-fass
http://example.com/neha
```

I am doing change in `.htaccess` file but something going wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Use [WP_Rewrite](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite) using the [Rewrite API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API)?

Answer (score 3):

Basically, Wordpress allows you to use SEO and user friendly URLs, just change your `permalink` settings in `Administration area -> Settings -> Permalinks` and set them to `Post name`.

More information - [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks).

Comment: yes allow but not for my plugin because i am not using custom post type for my own plugin to add mentor

Answer (score 0):

You can use wordpress plugin to edit url whatever you want like below:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/

Or search another on the same site which suits to your requirement

Comment: No i am using my own plugin to add mentor so custom post type plugin will not be compatible with my own plugin.i want to do this by htaccess

Answer (score 0):

The desired redirects could work for example like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&?mentor_slug=([^&]+)&?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /%2? [R=302,L]
```

Anyway, you should also define other cases, like:

Is it possible, that there are folders before the parameter? What should happen for example in the following case:
`http://example.com/mentor-profile/test/asd/albala/?mentor_slug=dr-jonathan-fass`
Should these folder be kept or be cut?

What should happen, if there are any other parameters, for example:
`http://example.com/mentor-profile/?test=asd&ala=balab&mentor_slug=dr-jonathan-fass&hi=hello`
Should other parameters be kept or be lost?